# Запретить прямой доступ к json файлу

Tags: php

Можно ли отследить что человек открыл по прямой ссылке json файл и вывести ему шаблон с ошибкой?
То есть условно:
**если ссылка открыта, то показать ему ошибку**
Знаю что можно просто закрыть доступ через .htaccess, но можно ли это сделать через php?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: есть сайт website.ru, если я открою по прямой ссылке website.ru/application/config/config.json то у меня покажет всё содержимое. могу ли я как то отследить что человек открыл этот файл? И если открыл то показать ему страницу 403

Comment: узнать можно лишь в логах. а чтобы пыха надо чтобы пыха отработала. А на jsonе пыхи нет

Comment: Переместите файл в каталог недоступный по ссылке. В php напишите скрипт, который считывает данный файл и выдаёт его контент. В скрипте можно реализовать любой алгоритм сесуретности и журналирования. Пользователь будет запрашивать скрипт и получать содержимое. Если не нравится, что пользователь будет запрашивать *.php скрипт, то в .htaccess можно создать правило перенаправления